# What should be Black's next move?

Tags: analysis

In this game, the last move made by white was **Bg5** . Now it's black's turn. A software analysis shows that black is winning in this position with -2.51 evaluation. I am unable to spot the black's next best move ? Any kind of hint is appreciated !

[image]

Comment: The position is dead equal according to my Stockfish. There's no forced win for Black here. Are you sure it's -2.51 pawns, not centipawns or something?

Comment: I was looking this position through the online software evaluation chessboard of http://grandchesstour.org/live-2016-sinquefield-cup-grand-chess-tour If you want you can check this out !

Comment: Can you provide a direct link to the game / position?

Comment: 1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nd7 5.Nf3 Ngf6 6.Qe2 Nxe4 7.Qxe4 Nf6 8.Qd3 Bg4 9.Be2 e6 10.O-O Be7
 11.Bg5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a deep analysis using a computer, just my 'at a glance' thoughts.

Here are my observations:

1. The pawn structure is typical for a Caro-Kann structure
2. Black is a little cramped
3. There is no forced win, so what you pick is a stylistic decision

These are the moves I would consider:

- **1...Qc7** or **1...O-O** are thematic in the Caro-Kann pawn structure
- **1...Nd5** offering a trade of dark square bishops would help relieve Black's cramped position
- **1...c5?!** is too soon, but Black would like to get this move in sometime to challenge White's space advantage
- **1...Bxf3?!**, although exchanges a bad bishop, I think this is too soon, and I would prefer to keep the pressure on the knight

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a bug in the chessboard's engine. If you look at the engine's main line, you'll see that it is bogus. After 11... h6, White will never sacrifice his bishop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

White is slightly better or at least equal. Black isn't threatening anything. Maybe there's a tactic involving playing e5 or c5 and giving white doubled f-pawns but that's not worth 2 1/2 pawns. Your engine is wrong. Analyze it with a modern engine like SF and let us know what it says.